# Put a statement iteratively in an if statement

Tags: sas

I need to write the following query in a loop. Is it possible ?

```
if a1 > 0
 or a2 > 0
 or a3 > 0
 or a20 > 0 then some_variable =dummy;
```

I am not able to think of any logic to this iteratively in a macro definition. The question asked is just a snapshot. Actual numbers vary till 200

Comment: Add the language tag.

Comment: I'm adding it given the [tag:sas] answer was accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going out on a limb to guess this is [sas](/questions/tagged/sas), since your previous question was and your question sounds SAS-like.

You could do this in an array, if it's using regular data step variables.

```
data want;
set have;
array a a1-a200;
if max(of a[*]) > 0 then some_variable=dummy;
run;
```

`max` would give you the largest number of the 200 variables, and if that is > 0 then you're good to go.  If your boolean condition is more complicated, you might have to loop through the array.

Comment: Yes tha language is SAS and thanks for a prompt response. This answer seems to work. But can you explain the background of max .used here. Sorry if my question is too lame.

Comment: `max()` gives the largest value in a set of variables provided.  `max(of ...)` is how you use a space separated list, so, `max(a,b,c)` = `max(of a b c)`.  (This is true in most similar functions.)  `a[*]` lists out all variables comprising the array `a`, so `a[*] = a1 a2 a3 a4 a5...a200`.  So `max(of a[*])` means `max(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,...,a200)`.  That gives the highest value; since you are checking for at least 1 value over 0, if the highest value is over 0, at least one value must be over 0, and if not, then no value must be over 0.

Comment: Thanks you are awesome Joe. Its so simple how you put it into words.

Comment: No need for the array declaration, simply `sum(of a1-a200) > 0` would also work.

Comment: I figured array was better, simply because the logic might be more complex and thus better to start with the array in case it was needed :)